# Apple watch in Interface controller modal not working Menu

Tags: modal-dialog, apple-watch

When I open Interface Controller with "presentControllerWithName", than MenuItem is displayed on this screen but does not work. I can't close this Menu and when you click on the menuItem, nothing happens.

Comment: What navigation type are you using in your app? "presentControllerWithName" is used to open modal windows so it should be working always. But are you using something else? hierarchical? page-based? both? Describe your problem a bit more and a bit better please